# .htaccess not working in xampp

Tags: windows, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

.htaccess is not working in my system. I have done the following things.

Included mod_rewrite.so file in httpd.conf file

and have changed all `Allowoverride None` to `Allowoverride All`

and have restarted the server. But still it is not working. Can anyone help me?

This is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^test\.html http://www.google.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can you define what `not working` is? Does it show a 500 internal error or does it cause pink fluffy unicorns to appear? Also posting the contents of your htaccess file might help.

Comment: It is not showing any errors. But if i place htaccess inside my folder nothing is happening because of that. Not even showing 500 internal server error if do any wrong things in my htaccess

Comment: Can you post the contents of your htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one reason why it might not be working:

You should add the following configuration directive in the server's virtual host file to allow the .htaccess file in the DocumentRoot directory. If the following lines are not added, the .htaccess file will not work:

```
</VirtualHost>
<Directory /var/www/test.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

see https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/beginners-guide-redirects-htaccess